# How to auto record how many times import csv data to mysql table?

Tags: mysql

For example , each time I import csv data to mysql table as follow:

```
id  col_a col_b
1    d     d
2    d     1
3    3     4
```

I want to add a field which records how many times I import it as follow:

```
id  col_a col_b record_times
1    d     d        1
2    d     1        1
3    3     4        1
4    d     d        2
5    d     1        2
6    3     4        2
7    d     d        3
8    d     1        3
9    3     4        3
```

I know how to [AUTO INCREMENT Field](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp), but I could not find how to set record_times to tell how many times I import a file.

## Env

- mysql: 5.5.47

Comment: so are you want to know how many times it will record? are you counting for each id?

Comment: not for each id,  but how to record import times. The example is not clear？

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-triggers/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write a trigger after insert to update that column value.
The value will be the maximum number of that column +1.

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub query to count the number of occurances <= id

```
SELECT *,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T T1 WHERE T1.COL_A = T.COL_A AND T1.COL_B = T.COL_B AND T1.ID <= T.ID) AS RECORDED_TIMES
FROM T
ORDER BY ID;
```

replace T with your table name